# Branch.io can't receive sms (testing)

Tags: sms, branch.io

i am trying to use branch.io ... Set up  all my environment, but i don't receive the sms with the testlink to click on my phone.

(I'm located in Germany, europe)

I've tried to insert my number, but i don't receive any sms. (Status on the website said it was send)

Tried with +49 prefix (for Germany) but nothing works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Nico, we use Twilio for our text-me-the-app feature. It generally works well, but sometimes we get reports that a message didn't go through, despite Twilio's service indicating that it did. In the past we've discovered carrier specific issues that were at fault.

Appending +49 or 49 is definitely the right move. We can check our logs and also Twilio's logs to look for problems. Can you try again (so that we can look at recent logs), then send a note with your phone number to support@branch.io? Thanks, and sorry for the problems.

Comment: please let us know if this continues to be a problem. We definitely want to get this figured out